# Set width to 100% of "leftover" on a row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use Bootstrap as my framework.

I have 5 inputs.
4 inputs got it´s width in pixels.
Now i´d like the 5th input to use the rest of the width, without breaking row.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" style="width: 50px" />
<input type="text" style="width: 50px" />
<input type="text" style="width: 100%" /> //Resposive!
<input type="text" style="width: 50px" />
<input type="text" style="width: 50px" />
```

I´d like to have that one responsive!

If i use this code, the line will be 100% of window and break rows.
How will i manage this?

**EDIT**
I should mention that the input is in a "inline-form"!!

Comment: @Vitorinofernandes This works perfect! Please post it as an answear!

Comment: That's not how Bootstrap work at all. If you use a framework and end up just using your own style, then it's much better to not use the framework from the beginning.

Comment: @AvAvt Well. I use small parts of custom design. Maby 10%. So, i won´t leave Bootstrap!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

apply `width:calc(100% - 200px);` for your input box it will solve your problem

Answer (score 2):

Flexbox can do that:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
div {
  display: flex;
}
input {
  width: 50px;
}
input:nth-of-type(3) {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div>
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
</div>
```